# Git patch and calculate SHA

Tags: git, sha, git-patch

To avoid XY I will explain my goal:

I am writing a *RunManager* which should execute a process of given version. I want to add an option to run the process with the current directory contents (including uncommitted changes), **and tag those changes** somehow with a deterministic name.

What I'm thinking is to create a git patch, **give it a SHA as if it was a commit**, copy it to the remote server and apply.

How can I acheive the SHA part?

Comment: The git command to produce the SHA itself is `git hash-object path/to/said/object`, but I'm unsure of what exactly you want to include in your patch, and a patch is not a commit... I'm confused.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for your help! The patch should include all the uncommitted changes, including new file. Applying it should modify the file-system so it is exactly as it is now.

Comment: @RomainValeri git diff > tmp.patch && git hash-object tmp.patch working!

Comment: You could also commit all the changes to a temporary branch and use the regular push/pull commands. There might even be something in the low-level git plumbing commands that would let you do this without touching the working copy, its current branch, or its current index in any way.